# Looking for a book about Math

Tags: reference-request

This may be almost entirely off topic so i apologize to the moderators in advance. Please redirect or suggest.

I read a book a number of years that was absolutely phenomenal and i have yet to find it again. I have scoured the internet in pursuit of this book to no avail. It was a short little book with a number of chapters that explained a mathematical theory in a cute or clever way, probably for children. The great thing about the book was that it was illustrated with really odd and random pictures of creatures or scenes that usually related to whatever the chapter was about. The writing style was almost poetic explaining how things like how "1+1 doesnt equal 2" (one of the chapters if i am correct) in almost a Dr Seuss sort of a way. It sounds a little bit like a mathematical Lewis Carroll novel. Id say the book was fairly old, easily in the mid to early 1900's. I know its a long shot, but being the math enthusiasts we all are, im wondering if anyone recalls a book by this definition.  To make this more MO worthy, if any math work fits this description, i would be interested as well.

Comment: While I am not convinced this is the book you are describing, you might enjoy Norman Juster's children's book [The Dot and the Line:  A Romance in Lower Mathematics](http://www.amazon.com/dp/1587170663/ref=wl_it_dp_o_pC_S_ttl?_encoding=UTF8&colid=MYPJ1Z7NMBDQ&coliid=I3UIQ9M0LYY1DT).